# Can this multinomial probability query performance be improved?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I'd like to get the probability that some N samples of M equiprobable events does not have any case of the M possible individual outcomes having more than some maximum value.

The code I'm using on Mathematica 11 is:

```
Probability[Max[Array[x, bins]] <= max, Array[x, bins] \[Distributed] 
             MultinomialDistribution[balls, ConstantArray[1/bins, bins]]]
```

But, this gets very slow with cases I'm interested in. For example:

> {balls, bins, max} = {100, 10, 20}

has been running for several minutes on my reasonably fast 4-core Intel laptop.

Can the performance be improved in any way to get cases like this or similar magnitude of values to finish in less time?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an old function I cooked up for this very scenario: PMF of the maximum of categories in a multinomial with equal category probabilities:

```
pMax[balls_, bins_, max_, p_: Infinity] := Module[{h},
   h[0, n_, m_] = N[1, p];
   h[s_, n_, m_] := h[s, n, m] = Sum[(n*x + x - s) (h[s - x, n, m]/x!), {x, Min[s, m]}]/s;
   balls! h[balls, bins, max]/bins^balls];

{balls, bins, max} = {50, 7, 10};

r1 = pMax[balls, bins, max]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

r2 = Probability[Max[Array[r, bins]] <= max, 
     Array[r, bins] \[Distributed] 
      MultinomialDistribution[balls, ConstantArray[1/bins, bins]]]; //
   AbsoluteTiming // First

%/%%

r1 == r2
```

> 0.00363067
>
> 181.405
>
> 49964.7
>
> True

So, about 50,000X faster than built-in on a smaller example than the OP (I got tired of waiting for the built-in to finish on that example, but it was over half an hour running before I killed it, on a fairly beefy laptop.)

The OP case:

```
pMax[100, 10, 20]; // AbsoluteTiming//First
```

> 0.0102418

This can handle pretty big cases.

You may need to increase `$RecursionLimit` for larger cases.

The last optional argument allows use of inexact calculations. In use, its value is generally of the order of the # of balls, but experiment - it varies with case characteristics. You'll get the indication of "No significant digits are available to display" warning if too small. In any case, a nice performance boost can be had then if exact results are not required:

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 50000}, pMax[5000, 300, 30, 5000] // N[#] &] // AbsoluteTiming
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 50000}, pMax[5000, 300, 30] // N[#] &] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.918627,0.727751}
>
> {15.452,0.727751}

Caveat: This is an old quick-and-dirty, it has no real error checking, so feed it nonsense values at your own peril.