# Can this probability function speed be improved?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I have a process that as part of it requires a certain probability query, specifically, given a multinomial distribution with *f* equiprobable categories and *r* trials, some specific category has a given value *v* and that value is the (not necessarily unique) maximum across all categories.

This can obviously be done directly in *Mathematica* with

```
Probability[a[1] == v && v == Max[Array[a, f]], 
 Array[a, f] \[Distributed] MultinomialDistribution[r, ConstantArray[1/f, f]]]
```

but it is quite sluggish, for example with *{r,f,v}={25,12,6}* it takes some... well, I don't know, I aborted it after several minutes running.

I've come up with

```
f[r_, f_, v_] := 
  Block[{t}, 
   Coefficient[
    Expand[Sum[t^j/j!, {j, 0, v}]^(f - 1)] (f - 1)^(-(r - v))*
           (r - v)!*Binomial[r, v]/f^v (1 - 1/f)^(r - v), t^(r - v)]];
```

which is fairly snappy.

Can this query be done faster? I'd like to handle cases of *r* up to ~200, *f* up to ~25 and *v* generally ~*r/3*.

**Edit/Update:**

Using a technique from [an old answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186535/11467), the new function

```
f2[r_, f_, v_, pf_ : Infinity] := Module[{pMax},
   pMax[q_, b_, max_, p_] := Module[{h}, h[0, n_, m_] = N[1, p];
     h[s_, n_, m_] := 
      h[s, n, m] = 
       Sum[(n*x + x - s) (h[s - x, n, m]/x!), {x, Min[s, m]}]/s;
     q! h[q, b, max]/b^q];
   pMax[r - v, f - 1, v, pf] Binomial[r, v]/f^v (1 - 1/f)^(r - v)];
```

is notably faster on larger cases and comparable on small ones. For example, with *{r,f,v}={25,12,15}* this takes ~0.36ms, vs ~2.5ms for my original function. By way of comparison, the direct calculation in *Mathematica* took ~2800 seconds.

If no better result arrives, I'll self-answer with this function.

Comment: Here's is a (extremely?) minor speed improvement:  Change the `Coefficient[]` term to `If[r > v f, 0, Coefficient[Expand[Sum[t^j/j!, {j, 0, v}]^(f - 1)]` as the probability is zero if $r>v f$.  That way the `Expand` doesn't have to happen every time.  The only other suggestion I have is to look at the coefficients in the expansion to see if something matches in oeis.org.

Comment: @JimB - already done in auxiliary definitions I left out of OP for brevity. I'd already poked at OEIS with some tantalizing but eventually faulty hits, but will revisit. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Here's one more desperation level suggestion:  Some of the extreme results might be easier to simplify.  For example, if $2v>n$, then there can be only one category with a frequency of $v$.  The function that matches your function under that condition is  `f2[r_, f_, v_] := Binomial[r, v] (f - 1)^(r - v)/f^v`.  A little more complicated would be if $3v>n$ which would mean (I think) that there could only be at most 2 categories with the same value of $v$.

Comment: You're probably way ahead of me on this but maybe the following which uses a recurrence relation (rather than getting the associated coefficient) on a slightly different problem (not conditioning on a specific category having the maximum) might help:  https://www.pnas.org/content/104/27/11189.

Comment: @JimB ;-)  - I am testing right now with that very technique from an old answer of mine that I remembered about an hour ago: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186535/11467

It's looking promising for large cases, silly I didn't recognize I'd seen this kind of problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an extended comment:  Because the question is about speeding things up, I think you'll need to consider merging different functions depending on what values of $v$ are of most interest.  Here is an example of the timing:

```
f[r_, f_, v_] := Block[{t}, Coefficient[Expand[Sum[t^j/j!, {j, 0, v}]^(f - 1)] (f - 1)^(-(r - v))*
  (r - v)!*Binomial[r, v]/f^v (1 - 1/f)^(r - v), t^(r - v)]];

f2[r_, f_, v_, pf_ : Infinity] := Module[{pMax}, 
   pMax[q_, b_, max_, p_] := Module[{h}, h[0, n_, m_] = N[1, p];
     h[s_, n_, m_] := h[s, n, m] = Sum[(n*x + x - s) (h[s - x, n, m]/x!), {x, Min[s, m]}]/s;
     q! h[q, b, max]/b^q];
   pMax[r - v, f - 1, v, pf] Binomial[r, v]/f^v (1 - 1/f)^(r - v)];

(* This function only useful when 2v > r *)
f3[r_, f_, v_] := If[2 v > r, Binomial[r, v] (f - 1)^(r - v)/f^r]

r = 200;
g = 25;  (* Really this is f but I get confused between the constant f and the function f *)
data = ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0, 0}, r];
Do[data[[v]] = {v, If[2 v > r, AbsoluteTiming[Binomial[r, v] (g - 1)^(r - v)/g^v][[1]], 10],
   AbsoluteTiming[f[r, g, v]][[1]],
   AbsoluteTiming[f2[r, g, v]][[1]]}, {v, 1, r - 1}]

ListLogPlot[{data[[All, {1, 3}]], data[[All, {1, 4}]], data[[All, {1, 2}]]},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 9}}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"v", "Seconds"},
 PlotLegends -> {"f", "f2", "f3"}]
```

[image: Plot of timing for each of the 3 functions]

Comment: Don't know how I missed this (excellent) response. Mea culpa, +1 and accept.